# Magento 1 Issue- Shopping cart rule does not apply on Reorder from backend

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, sales-order, sales-quote, reorder

I am using **Magento EE ver. 1.14.2.4**
I have observed that shopping cart price rule does not apply on reorder from backend admin side.

It considers the original product amount instead of applying shopping cart price rule into order.

Scenario :-

1. **Add shopping cart rule for fix $20 discount on all products.**
2. **Add product, rule applied, order placed with shopping cart rule
   considered.** see here - [image]
3. **On reorder page shopping cart rule does on apply.** see here -
   [image]

Here is the shopping cart rule
[image]
[image]
**Is their any way i can see the order total data into quote,
so on reorder page the discount gets applied same as the order page ?**